# Android Auto Backup - ask user to login and select frequency?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am learning about how to implement backup/restore for android as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)
It is said that "Doesn't require a user to be logged into your app. The user must be logged into the device with a Google account.  Doesn't require a user to be logged into your app. The user must be logged into the device with a Google account."

But for example, if user isnt logged in any google account, can we ask within the app to login to google account and select frequency? For example, whatsapp is doing it on its settings? you can even change the account if you have multiple accounts? Otherwise user has to go to phone settings and has to enable this and most of the users dont even know that is available there.

So if I implement a google authentication within my app and get authentication token. how can I implement this? Any sample code or project?

I am using xamarin.android but I dont mind java code as well.

Answer (score -1):

The Auto Backup is provided by android. You can enable it in the system setting.
When you enable it, you can set the location to backup, for example set a google account or let it backup to SD card. And you could also set frequency and which app you need to backup. It all sets in the system setting not in the app.
You could refer to this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) for more information.